# Unity animation plays late when using OnTriggerEnter2D and OnTriggerStay2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, collision

I created a lighting effect animation within my game and it is activated each time an enemy collides with a lighting rod. However, I'm having a problem with the timing of when my lighting effect takes place; I haven't added a timer limit or using IEnumerator. Since I'm using the OnTriggerEnter2D function, enemies that have already collided with the lighting rod, my lighting effect animation doesn't play not until another enemy hits the collider. I'm guessing it's because the first enemy has already hit the collider and instead I would need to use the OnTriggerStay2D function, however this time the lighting effect animation only play plays seconds after the enemy has collided with the lighting rod and the whole animation doesn't look right. Is there a way to make my lighting effect animation play at the same time any enemies have collided with the lighting rod? 
My lighting effect animation is basically turning a blue panel on an off.

This is my script:

```
public Animator fadeAnim;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col) {  //Enter
    if (col.tag == "Enemy 1") {
        fadeAnim.SetBool ("flicker", true);
        StartCoroutine (wait ()); // this is meant for something else //
    }
```

}

Comment: Maybe your animation has an exit time : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html. Removing the exit time, or making it short may be a workaround.

Comment: It could be what Greg said i.e. there is "Has exit time" set at specific animation percentage or there is a transition time. When used with sprite animations the transition time is effectively a simple delay.